# how to get UILabel action in UITableView?

Tags: ios

I have 3 UILabels in each cell of a table. I have added tap gesture recognisers to each one, but when it is tapped, how can I get the index path of the row that was tapped?

Here is my code

```
UILabel *tit_lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,280,45)];
[tit_lbl setText:[[final_dictionaires_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:title]];
[tit_lbl setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[tit_lbl setTag:indexPath.row];
[btn addSubview:tit_lbl];
[tit_lbl release];

UITapGestureRecognizer* tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(goToArticleDetailsView:)];
[tit_lbl addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
[tapRecognizer release];
```

With this, I can get the label action but I want to get which label is clicked in which Row ?? (I have 3 labels in each row).

Comment: here is my code UILabel *tit_lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,280,45)];
        [tit_lbl setText:[[final_dictionaires_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:title]];
        [tit_lbl setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [tit_lbl setTag:indexPath.row];
        [btn addSubview:tit_lbl];
        [tit_lbl release];
        
        UITapGestureRecognizer* tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(goToArticleDetailsView:)];
            [tit_lbl addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
        [tapRecognizer release];

Comment: why don't you use UIButtons with custom style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the suggestions for using a button with a custom style instead of basically recreating buttons using labels and gesture recognisers. However, you'd still have the same problem. Which label was tapped? And which row of the table was it in?

You can find out which label was tapped by assigning tags to each one and then querying the `view` property of the gesture recogniser. The gesture recogniser will be the argument in your goToArticleDetailsView method:

```
-(void)goToArticleDetailsView:(id)sender
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR = (UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender;
    if (tapGR.view.tag == 1)
        // tapGR.view is the label that the gesture recognize was attached to
```

You can find out which row of the table was tapped using the gesture recogniser's `locationOfTouch` method, together with UITableView's `indexPathForRowAtPoint:` method:

```
CGPoint touchLocation = [tapGR locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *tappedRow = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchLocation];
```

Answer (score -1):

A UILabel can not be clicked. You should use the UITextfield if you want to let the user to interact with the values.

To get the action you should sent a message to the instance of UITextField.

To get the right cell you can use the "indexPath"

good luck

Comment: you can have an action for UILabel using UIGestureRecogniser.But in my case I want to detect which lebel and which row clicked ?

Comment: You can have a GestureRecognizer. But use Tag to know which row is clicked. If I am not wrong, the TapGestureRecognizer does not have a tag member variable. So Try to subclasse UITapGestureRecognizer with a tag variable.